# Good hash function for generating uint64 or uint32 feature id in sparse machine learning

Tags: java, c++, hash, machine-learning

I use hash function on feature string(such as query and title) to generate sparse feature id. This hash function should be efficient and has good distribution on uint64 or uint32. Can anyone give me some recommendations?
I have tested two methods in java.
The first is java hashCode. I found it has many collisions on similar geohash strings.
The second is blow. It has more collisions than hashCode.

```
public static long gene(String s) {
        long hash = 5381;
        int c;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

(Please ignore the difference between java long and c++ uint. All fine)

Comment: geohash uses a reduced alphabet. Generic hash functions very often assume a even distribution of the usage of characters. Therefor many collisions are to be expected. I would transform the geohash string into it's binary counterparts before hashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Murmurhash](https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/) and [cityhash](https://github.com/google/cityhash)

Comment: This library supports those hashes and a few more https://github.com/OpenHFT/Zero-Allocation-Hashing

Comment: That is what i wanted. Thanks.